# AngularJS material sidebar elements are inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have two problems with a sidebar in a ui-router view.

You can check in the live demo:

1. The sidebar don't fill the vertical screen layout.

   [image: Example]
2. And the event click just work when I click in the text (button).

   [image: Example]

#### Code

```
<section layout="row" flex>
<md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
    <md-content layout-padding>
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item md-ink-ripple>
                <a class="md-button" href="/contact">
                    Contact
            </a>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
<md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding" ui-view>
</md-content>
```

Complete code: https://github.com/drog/Starter-project/blob/master/src/client/app/navbar/navbar.html

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: FYI, your demo link isn't working

Comment: A link to a private off-site demo has no long-term value for others, as the link will likely become invalid. Instead, use snippets or a reliable fiddle host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem two with the next code

```
<md-list>
        <div ui-sref="contact">
            <md-list-item md-ink-ripple>
                    Contact
            </md-list-item>
        </div>
    </md-list>
```

source: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2131#issuecomment-113938582